# Freeing memory error?

Tags: c++, memory, free, allocation, delete-operator

I need to free the `bitpointer`, because this function is executed multiple times and memory usage is growing for a reason I don't understand and it crashes after reaching 22mb of ram usage.. If I try to delete the `bitpointer` like this `delete []bitpointer` or `free(bitpointer)`I get access violation error. But I don't understand why, because the function shouldn't use the pointer any more and the new red blue green values are set..

```
void Get_Color(int x,int y,int w,int h,int &red,int &green,int &blue,int action)
{
    HDC hdc, hdcTemp;
    RECT rect;
    BYTE*bitPointer=new BYTE[4*h*w];
    HWND Desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    hdc = GetDC(Desktop);
    GetWindowRect(Desktop, &rect);
    hdcTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    BITMAPINFO bitmap;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = h;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    HBITMAP hBitmap2 = CreateDIBSection(hdcTemp, &bitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&bitPointer), NULL, NULL);
    SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap2);
    BitBlt(hdcTemp, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, x, y, SRCCOPY);
    if(action==1)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=w*h*4;j+=4)
        {
            red = bitPointer[j+2];
            green = bitPointer[j+1];
            blue = bitPointer[j];
            if(red<30 && green>190 && blue>190)
            {
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=w*h*4;j+=4)
        {
            red = bitPointer[j+2];
            green = bitPointer[j+1];
            blue = bitPointer[j];
            break;

        }   
    }
    ///RELEASE
    ReleaseDC(NULL,hdc);
    ReleaseDC(NULL,hdcTemp);
    delete []bitPointer; ///Error
}
```

Comment: the exact error msg..

Comment: Unhandaled exception at 0xWHATEVA (msvcr110d.dll) in my.exe 0xWHATEVA: Access violation reading location 0xWHATEVA  I can break or continue.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll see that you shouldn't be allocating memory for `bitPointer`, `CreateDIBSection` does that for you. You need to use `DeleteObject` to free `hBitmap2`.

The crash occurs because the value of `bitPointer` youi are freeing is not the one that you allocated. (And the memory you allocated is leaked.)

Comment: Thanks, you answer did help me as well, i was able to detect the last leak, thank you as well!

Answer (score 2):

In SelectObject, save the returned value: `HGDIOBJ save = SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap2);`

Then before ReleaseDC, delete the DIB `DeleteObject( SelectObject(hdcTemp, save) );`

Otherwise, you create bitmaps and don't delete them.

Comment: Okay dude, your solution did fix some of the issues, but there is still another one, which is lot smaller, but i still keep growing memory somewhere. 32 kbits per second or somthing :D

Comment: Use `DeleteDC` for hdcTemp. `ReleaseDC` is necessary for `GetDC` and you have `CreateCompatibleDC`. I hope this is the other leak.

Comment: Hah, yep, that was a leak, but there is one last leak :D Very small. I hope ypu can find it, but you still were very helpful! :) EDIT- i guess i found it myself. BYTE*bitPointer=new BYTE[4*h*w];

Comment: The final delete will work also as `delete bitPointer` without [].